# How can I detect if labels run off the plot area in a ggplot2 plot?

Tags: r, text, plot, ggplot2

I have some code that I frequently use to generate large batches of bar graphs. The bars are clustered by labels along the x axis and then each individual bar has a label on top of the bar itself. Sometimes the text for the individual bar label runs off the top of the plot area and is truncated--depending on the length of the x axis label, the length of the individual bar label, and the height of the bar itself.

I can manually adjust the `scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,100))` for each plot to make it look nice. For example if a bar goes up to 100% in height but has a very long label, I might use: `scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,140),breaks=c(0,25,50,75,100))`. This stops the y-axis tick marks at 100% but leaves extra room at the top of the plot area for my label. If a bar only goes up to 40% and has a short label, leaving the y limits at c(0,140) looks bad as there is too much white space above the 100% mark.

Because I make tons of these plots, I'd like a way to automatically determine how to set the limits for `scale_y_continuous` for each plot. Doing it manually is too time-consuming.

Is there a way to test whether a label is truncated or runs off the plot area? If so, I could just iterate my way to a nice looking plot by testing to see if a label is cut off and then expanding the y limit a little bit until there is no truncation.

Comment: I'm not sure if that's possible, but you can probably generally estimate how long a label will be based on the number of characters and use that to adjust your plot--no iteration necessary.  If you want to be more precise, you can use a monospace font.

Comment: As @SamDickson said, you can make a rough estimate of how long the label can be and then set your labels to automatically add line breaks if they exceed the cutoff. For example, `paste(strwrap("The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog", 20), collapse="\n")` will wrap a string so that each line has no more than 20 characters.

Comment: If you've got time on your hands, you might actually be able to calculate when a string will run off the end of the plot. It will require figuring out the width of the `grob` (graphical object) in which the text is written, the width of the text itself, and the location of the text within the grob. The width of the text can be determined using `strwidth`, e.g., `strwidth(c(LETTERS, letters, " "), units="inches", family="Arial")` gives you the widths of all characters in the Arial font.

Comment: I'm a bit hazy on how to figure out the size of grobs and how to calculate string widths in the same normalized coordinate units as the grob, but I think it can be done.

Answer (score 6):

I don' think this can be done.  And I think this comes down to you not fully understanding the grammar on which `ggplot2` is based. Specifically how `ggplot` maps from data values to aesthetic values.

This can be understood intuitively with a simple thought experiment:

```
library(ggplot2)
data(mtcars)
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg, label = rownames(mtcars)))
# consider
p + geom_text()
# vs 
p + geom_text(size= 15)
```

What is the difference between the first plot `p + geom_text()` and the second `p + geom_text(size=15)`? From a data (structural) perspective, they are the same. The only difference is the scaling used to map from data elements to aesthetics. But my understanding is that the mapping from data elements to pixel elements is not stored; so you are not able to view the resulting positions.

This hunch seems clear from examining the structure of the `ggplot` object:

```
p2 <- p + geom_text()
str(p2)
List of 9
 $ data       :'data.frame':    32 obs. of  11 variables:
  ..$ mpg : num [1:32] 21 21 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 ...
  ..$ cyl : num [1:32] 6 6 4 6 8 6 8 4 4 6 ...
  ..$ disp: num [1:32] 160 160 108 258 360 ...
  ..$ hp  : num [1:32] 110 110 93 110 175 105 245 62 95 123 ...
  ..$ drat: num [1:32] 3.9 3.9 3.85 3.08 3.15 2.76 3.21 3.69 3.92 3.92 ...
  ..$ wt  : num [1:32] 2.62 2.88 2.32 3.21 3.44 ...
  ..$ qsec: num [1:32] 16.5 17 18.6 19.4 17 ...
  ..$ vs  : num [1:32] 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 ...
  ..$ am  : num [1:32] 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  ..$ gear: num [1:32] 4 4 4 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 ...
  ..$ carb: num [1:32] 4 4 1 1 2 1 4 2 2 4 ...
 $ layers     :List of 2
  ..$ :Classes 'proto', 'environment' <environment: 0x0000000015eb15f8> 
  ..$ :Classes 'proto', 'environment' <environment: 0x0000000015f6d0a0> 
 $ scales     :Reference class 'Scales' [package "ggplot2"] with 1 field
  ..$ scales: list()
  ..and 23 methods, of which 9 are  possibly relevant:
  ..  add, clone, find, get_scales, has_scale, initialize, input, n, non_position_scales
 $ mapping    :List of 3
  ..$ x    : symbol wt
  ..$ y    : symbol mpg
  ..$ label: language rownames(mtcars)
 $ theme      : list()
 $ coordinates:List of 1
  ..$ limits:List of 2
  .. ..$ x: NULL
  .. ..$ y: NULL
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "cartesian" "coord"
 $ facet      :List of 1
  ..$ shrink: logi TRUE
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "null" "facet"
 $ plot_env   :<environment: R_GlobalEnv> 
 $ labels     :List of 3
  ..$ x    : chr "wt"
  ..$ y    : chr "mpg"
  ..$ label: chr "rownames(mtcars)"
 - attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "gg" "ggplot"
```

As you can see, there is no storage of the coordinate pixel locations of the various geometric objects (text in this case). I would guess that this is because `ggplot2` is meant to be used interactively, but that's just a guess. That is, you can easily change a plot. The only reason you keep a plot around is via `ggsave` or one of `grDevices` functions (`png`, etc), in which case the graphic is saved to a file.

If you view Figure 3.7 in Hadley's book on ggplot, which is a schematic representation of the graphic generation process, it seems to be the case that storing of the mapping from data elements to pixel locations is not saved, but generated each time.

... If someone with deeper understanding of `ggplot`'s inner workings / has examined the source code knows differently, please chime in and I'll update or delete my answer.

Comment: Thank you for this. It took me a little while before I had the time to really read and digest your answer. It is interesting that these coordinates are not stored since clearly there are many instances where people want to store their ggplot2 results but the creators of ggplot2 obviously have much better insight into this than I do.

Comment: @Andrew, if it was that helpful, an upvote and an accept would be appreciated.